# Interaction between Hexproof and "target of an opponent's choice"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There exist a small number of cards which have targets chosen by an opponent. While it is old, the most straightforward one I can find is [Cuombajj Witches](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCuombajj%20Witches%5d) which has the ability:

> {T}: Cuombajj Witches deals 1 damage to any target and 1 damage to any target of an opponent's choice.

Suppose I have only one opponent, both players control a Hexproof creature, and I control a Cuombajj Witches. If I activate Cuombajj Witches' ability, I can choose to target my own Hexproof creature for one point of damage.

However, when my *opponent* chooses targets, are they also allowed to choose my Hexproof creature for 1 damage? Or are they allowed to choose their own Hexproof creature, as they could for their own spells and abilities? The first seems more likely to me, but I could see it either way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is the first one, they can choose to target your Hexproof creature.

The full meaning of Hexproof is:

> 702.11b “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities **your opponents control**.”

The person who activated Cuombajj Witches is controller of the ability. It doesn't matter that your opponent is making a choice.

The process for casting a spell or activating an ability starts with defining the controller:

> 601.2a To propose the casting of a spell, a player first moves that card (or that copy of a card) from where it is to the stack. It becomes the topmost object on the stack. It has all the characteristics of the card (or the copy of a card) associated with it, **and that player becomes its controller**.

And for Activated abilities:

> 602.2a The player announces that they are activating the ability. If an activated ability is being activated from a hidden zone, the card that has that ability is revealed. That ability is created on the stack as an object that’s not a card. It becomes the topmost object on the stack. It has the text of the ability that created it, and no other characteristics. **Its controller is the player who activated the ability.** The ability remains on the stack until it’s countered, it resolves, or an effect moves it elsewhere.